# Need to display decimal values in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to display the 3 decimal values if the number having decimal value,
for suppose the number does not having decimal then will display zero's after decimal
I tried with TO_CHAR function but when i am converting to_char into TO_NUMBER it's displaying number with rounded values

Comment: TO_CHAR(pAmount, '9,999,999.999'); - have you try this ?

Comment: is this within an Oracle GUI client or in code/query?

Comment: Have you tried to use NUMBER(6,2) ?

Comment: For display you should use `TO_CHAR`. Converting back to number puts the format problem into the application layer(is a number and is not Oracle's problem how you display it.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but I guess you need something like

```
TO_CHAR(n, '999G990D000')
```

to show the zeros.

Answer (score 0):

If you have privileged to change the SCHEMA, then you can do it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME Modify Attrib Number(10,3);
```